# Web application - cache architecture

Tags: .net, architecture, data-structures, caching

I have a .Net application and a WCF service which I use to cache items in chronological order using `SortedSet`. It stores some meta data which I use to retrieve the DatabaseId so then the query to the Db would be much speedier. I need help on the best/right/most appropriate architecture.

The Service holds a SortedSet in a singleton. The data stored is

```
public class MyData : IComparable<MyData> {
    DateTime CreateDate {get; set;}
    List<int> AccountIds {get; set;}
    long DatabaseId {get; set;}

    // implementation to sort by CreateDate
}
```

I have a method which has the contract

```
List<int> GetDatabaseIds( DateTime startRange, DateTime endRange, 
    List<int> accountIds )
```

This method would then go through the `SortedSet`, use the `GetViewBetween` (using the `CreateDate` field), then issue a LINQ query to return only the DatabaseIds where the AccountIds match.

This speeds up the database retrieval, but as the number of records grow, so will the memory requirements. I have experimented with AppFabric Cache, MemCached and found them not usable as they store items in Key/Value. Maybe I am wrong, but can these products be used, if so how? If not, what other ways can I be using to store sequential data ( by date ) to get the matching DatabaseIds ?

**Update**

The reason I why I am doing this is that searching through the database directly is rather slow, and the items that get stored in the database are not always in chronological order. If I can just pass in the DatabaseId, the database only needs to do a seek on the PK. It would also allow me to use MemCached to store the data further minimizing db access. This is the higher up purpose. Also, I would need the web-servers to scale, which is why I moved it out of the Runtime.Cache to something external.

I am not 100% certain that I truly need this sort of caching, but when I was querying the database directly, there would be a much larger lag even with the right indexes in place. Using this method, the WCF search returns results in about 20ms (with about 1,000,000 records) and the db query would be very quick (can't recall the timing). I am also weary that as usage starts to climb, this WCF wouldn't scale.

Also, I did think about storing the entire SortedList into the Cache, and but the casting to/from/constant adding made it rather slow.

I expect the number of rows to increase by at least 10,000 / day and records are added at any time via another WCF method.

Maybe what I've done is completely wrong, but a few things I've thought of are:

1. Create a new table in the Db that stores exactly as I have in the cache. This would be clustered by the CreateDate and highly indexed
2. Keep trying to optimise the query / database so the query would be much faster
3. Keep the WCF Service, but have create a new ExpiryDate field, and have that record expire, that way old stuff not used won't be lingering round.

Ideas??

Comment: Can you explain the higher level purpose of this? i.e. without caching, what should this do?

Comment: What prevents you from storing the entire list as a single object? You can cast it back to its type and go over it.

Comment: I think this might be an interesting question, but I am with Dave, the end result/purpose is not entirely clear.

Comment: If you're not sure you need it, I'd recommend putting more effort into using the existing db, rather than making the whole system more complex by adding another component (and potential point of failure/maintenance).

Comment: @GrandmasterB - I believe I will be removing it fairly soon, but I'd like to know ideas of what others have used and see what would work best

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom cache like the one I have here: http://www.itsalltechnical.com/2011/01/non-web-expiring-generic-cache-in-c.html

I mention this because you can customize the way that you retrieve the data if you don't like the dictionary style access.  I think in most caching structure you will see that same dictionary methodology, so you may be cornered there.  You could consider using some other type of highspeed object based persistence such as MongoDB or Cassandra (works for facebook) for throughput.  Fortunately, you have a lot of options.